# How to customize form prototype in Symfony?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony

I work with symfony 3 and I have a html form I would like to customize using the prototype.

This is an example of prototype I already use (in a HTML attribute) :

```
data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.entity.vars.prototype)|e }}"
```

I'd like to know how to inject html code into the prototype so I would be able to get specific html structure  ?

In my case, the actual html code I got is :
[Actual html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiYKX.png)

I want to inject a html code (in green) :
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaJDa.png)

I'd like to change the part of the html form. The html form is added with JavaScript code. How could I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show more of your code? You controller, and this appears to be a twig template, show that code too please.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-a-collection-prototype